# fancy way to load contents of a CSV file into a dictionary<string,string> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, file-io

I know how to do this via streamreader and read to the end of line, but was curious if there was a fancier way of going it (for the sake of learing).

```
filename: blah.csv
```

File layout is simple:

```
"Some234234        ", 234
"blahblha234234    ", 2322
```

I want to load this into a dictionary  (the second part should be a int, but I will parse later in case of errors).

Can you do this via linq somehow?

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.  (There's nothing wrong with using it in C#.

Remember that CSV is a much more complicated file format than you think; both quotes and newlines can be escaped.

Comment: Very true, and I have used it many times this way for complex csv's or csv's with unpredictable contents. But this is only necessary if you expect a complex file. In some cases it's a very simple file, for example all integer values.

Answer (score 4):

CSV can be a lot more complicated than it appears at first.  Here is an excellent library for reading CSV files.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: I agree with this and with SLaks's reply.  The most effective way to solve any problem is to use a solution that already exists.  CSV seems to be one of those features that's just simple enough for people to re-invent on a whim, but still complex enough for most of them to make a mess out of.

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path) {
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path)) {
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}

var data = (from line in ReadLines(path)
            select line.Split(','))
           .ToDictionary(
              arr => arr[0].Trim('"', ' '),
              arr => int.Parse(arr[1].Trim()));
```

Comment: This will not handle escaped CSV files.  Even if the CSV files aren't escaped right now, they might be in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(filename)) {
 var vals = s.Split(',')
 dictionary[vals[0]] = vals[1];
}
```

No LINQ but this is simple really.  Doesn't handle embedded ',''s in the first value though.

Comment: This will not handle escaped CSV files.  Even if the CSV files aren't escaped right now, they might be in the future.

Comment: He obviously doesn't care about things like this as he put it "for the sake of learing." CSV isn't even a standardized format, his CSV might not allow escaping.

Answer (score 2):

```
 string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\dictionary.txt");

      Dictionary<string, string> b = (from p in file
                                     let x = p.Split(',')
                                     select x).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Comment: This will not handle escaped CSV files.  Even if the CSV files aren't escaped right now, they might be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could use File.ReadAllLines(), Select() and ToDictionary() to do this:

```
var d = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select( l => {
  var split = l.Split(',');
  return new { Key = split[0], Value = split[1] };
} ).ToDictionary( p => p.Key, p => p.Value );
```

But there are obvious problems here with respect to error handling and robustness, and as you add those, it gets worse and worse. I don't feel there's a particular good reason prefer LINQ or its extension methods here, as it isn't buying you much. The straightforward ways, posted already, are much cleaner.

EDIT: Sid's answer, for example, contains essentially the same code, but written in a much, much cleaner form by avoiding all this "fancy" junk.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill in your simple scenario, but for CSV to strongly typed collection conversion, I usually use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

It's a great tool to have in the tool box.

Comment: How can i use filehelpers to load CSV into the pregenereterd OR classes that can be used in LINQ2SQL instead of creating new class and assigning each damn field to it? I have a old school table with 300+ columns.. yay

Comment: I don't know your "pregenerated OR classes", but if minimizing code and violate SRP is okay, I guess you could use the same types and add the appropriate FileHelpers attributes. Personally, I'd separate the concerns, and map from the FileHelper types to the L2S types with AutoMapper.